# If $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow Y$ is a function then $Y$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

There are two parts a) if $f$ is one to one and b) if $f$ is onto.

I am really struggling with the concept of countable.  I know that a set is countable if a one to one and onto function can be written to $Z^+$.  If I only know that the function is one to one or onto I am getting stuck with how to prove that $Y$ is countable.

Comment: I assume \Z should be $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If $(a)$ means 'injective', then this is not true. For instance, let $f:\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the injection $f(x)=x$. This is one-to-one, but $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable.

Comment: your statement is definitely false because take Y as real numbers or $(0,1)$

Answer (score 0):

If $f:\mathbb{Z} \to Y$ is a *surjective* (onto) function, then $Y$ is countable. This can be taken as the defining property of a countable set. Note that your definition of countable would exclude finite sets, because if there were a one-to-one correspondence (i.e., a bijection) from a finite set to $\mathbb{Z}$, then the finite set would have to be, well, infinite.

The surjectivity condition intuitively means that $\mathbb{Z}$ has "at least as many" elements as $Y$.

As a counterexample to your claim (a), $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable. Yet there is an injective (one-to-one) function $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(n) = n$.

Note also that injectivity of the map $f$ in my counterexample means that $\mathbb{R}$ has "at least as many" elements as $\mathbb{Z}$, which makes sense since $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable and $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

The following is from Munkres' Topology: $B$ is an arbitrary set that for you would be $Y$.

[image]

He concludes that $B$ is countable by using the fact that, upon restricting the codomain of $g$ to $g(B)$, we obtain a bijection $B \leftrightarrow g(B) \subset \mathbb{Z}_+$, and the latter set $g(B)$ is clearly countable.

It's hard to tell, but if you are trying to prove the result of countability from a surjection $f:\mathbb{Z} \to B$ rather than from a surjection $\mathbb{Z}_+ \to B$, just use the fact that there exists a bijection $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_+ \to\mathbb{Z}$, so that you can revert attention to the surjection $f \circ \phi:\mathbb{Z}_+ \to B$.